# Spring Controller, how to break out of a loop based on a new HttpRequest?

Tags: java, spring, controller, while-loop, session-scope

I have a Spring @Controller. Inside the controller there is a method that after a specific request enters a while loop, which checks for new data and breaks only when data is found:

```
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end && controllersDataStore.getAutoupdate() == eventAutoUpdate ) {

        gridData = (GenericGrid) dsEventLogService.retrieveNewEventGridRows(gridHelper);
        if(gridData.getAaData().size()==0){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(POLLING_INTERVAL);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
```

I need to break out of the loop in certain cases even if data is not found, after a specific user action. So I need from a new HttpRequest, to be able to break from the previous while loop.

Also I need this to be per user, so one user can not interact with another user actions.

A controller is a singleton so it has common properties in all sessions. This means that we can not store a state in a global property and then check inside the loop for a change so it can break, because this will not be a per session property.

Is there any way to do that besides having the controller to have a session scope? (Which I am not even sure if it will work).

Thank you in advance, I will appreciate any tip.

Comment: A session-scoped controller is the easiest solution to this, why are you reluctant to try it?

Comment: I am reluctant because controllers are not supposed to be session-scoped. I was wondering if there is a "better" solution.

Comment: Says who?  Scoped controllers is a perfeclty valid thing to do.

Comment: because servlets (controllers) are managed by the container, the container instantiate only one instance of the servlet to handle requests from all users. making it session-scoped violates the whole concept doesn't it?

Comment: also, I can not find anything about session-scoped controllers whcih makes me believe that there must be some other way to do this. But then again maybe there isn't.

Comment: Servlets are managed by the container, controller are managed by Spring. The two lifecycles have no relation to each other. How about you actually try it and see?

Answer (score 1):

Store a keepRunning value in a db config table and after n seconds check this too.

A separate request in a different controller can update the state variable independently from this controller.

Comment: hi, i need one variable per session though, how will I differentiate between users?

Comment: Use the HttpSession to store this keepRunning flag. Per user, in-memory, thread-safe, and works in a clustered environment.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand. If I store it in HttpSession I do not have access to it from inside the while loop. Because the variable will be modified in a different request, thus in a different session instance. Am I wrong?